# Swing in eclipse can't access class sun.java2d.loops

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, intellij-idea

I was using IntelliJ everything was working, but when I sent the project to my friend ( he uses Eclipse), he wasn't able to run it 
[image: Secreenshoot of the error]

Here is the Class JPanelImage 
I think the redefinition of ( drawComponent ) is the problem

```
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    try {
        BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(new File( image));
        BufferedImage jImage ;
        g.drawImage(bImage, 2, 2, (int) getSize().getWidth(), (int) getSize().getHeight(), this);
       for(int k=0;k<joueurs.size();k++) {
            jImage= ImageIO.read(new File(Graphiques.Pions[joueurs.get(k).getId()]));
            System.out.println("Affichage des joueurs X:"+32*(int)(k%2) +" Y:"+ (getSize().getHeight()/2-40*(k/2)));
            g.drawImage(jImage,32*(k%2), (int) getSize().getHeight()/2-40*(int)(k/2),28,40, this);

        }
        if(artefact!=null){
            jImage= ImageIO.read(new File("./res/images/tresors/"+artefact.getElementArtefact()+".png"));
            g.drawImage(jImage,60, 8,28,40, this);
        }

        if(zone!=null){

           switch (zone.getTypeSelection()){
               case 0:
                   setBorder(Graphiques.INACTIVE_BORDER);
                break;
               case 1:
                   setBorder(Graphiques.ACTIVE_BORDER_SELECTED);
                   break;
               case 2:
                   setBorder(Graphiques.ACTIVE_BORDER_SHORE_HOVER);
                   break;
           }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I his version of Java the same as yours?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) But **don't attempt to load resources in a paint method.** Load the image once, in the constructor or an initialization method, and store it as an attribute of the class.

Comment: Sure, in Java 9 `sun.*` is not accessible by default.

Comment: what version should he install ?

Comment: He can use Java 8. If he use Java 9 and 10 it has to be configure to make `sun.java2d.loops` accesible and on the command line additional parameters are required. Do you want and answer how to configure the project in Eclipse for that?

Comment: of course @howlger  , instead of changing the jdk he will just configure Eclipse ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **Java 9 and Java 10 the `sun.*` packages are not accessible by default** (no public API: use at your own risk).

To make it accessible, you have to do the following in Eclipse:

1. In the menu choose ***Project > Properties***
2. In ***Java Build Path***, in the tab ***Libraries*** select the ***Modulepath > JRE System Library [JavaSE-9] > Is modular*** node and click ***Edit...***
3. In the tab ***Details***, in the section ***Added exports*** click ***Add...***
4. Enter the following:

   - Source module: **`java.desktop`**
   - Package: **`sun.java2d.loops`**

[image]